# SAS retain Statement to drag values down

Tags: sas

Following is an example of the data I have

```
data testretain;
input SUBJ  visit parameter value    vistype$   basevalue$;
cards; 
        01  1           1       152     screen      .   
        01  1           2       22      screen      .
        01  1           3       1000    screen      .
        01  2           1       154     random      YES
        01  2           2       23      random      YES
        01  2           3       1005    random      YES
        01  3           1       155     visit       .
        01  3           2       21      visit       .
        01  3           3       1003    visit       .
;
run;
```

I want to make sure that the `value` if the `basevalue` is `YES`gets carried over to each visit

so that it looks like the following- This is how I want the output to look like

```
    SUBJ visit    parameter   value   vistype$  basevalue$ BASE;

        01  1           1       152     screen      .   
        01  1           2       22      screen      .
        01  1           3       1000    screen      .
        01  2           1       154     random      YES    154
        01  2           2       23      random      YES     23
        01  2           3       1005    random      YES   1005
        01  3           1       155     visit       .      154 
        01  3           2       21      visit       .       23 
        01  3           3       1003    visit       .     1005
```

I tried the following code;

```
data testretain1;
set testretain;
if basevalue='YES' then BASE=value;
retain BASE;
run;
```

However it doesn't seem to work. The `1005` value gets dragged on to every observation.

Comment: It looks like you have two values for every visit.  Is there some other variable that distinguishes between the two values?  If so then include that in your ordering so that end up with 176,172,170 in one group and 52,51,50 in another group.  Then your program is much closer to being right.

Comment: I agree with Tom, you likely have another variable to distinguish these records that may make this problem trivial.

Comment: @Tom I updated the example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort the data so that all the results for the same parameter are together then you can easily use RETAIN to solve this.

```
data want;
  set have ; 
  by subject parameter visit;
  if first.parameter then BASE=.;
  if basevalue='YES' then BASE=value;
  retain BASE;
run;
```